# I'm lost at attempting to solve this two-dimensional Stochastic Differential Equation?

Tags: differential, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following two-dimensional SDE:
$dX_1=(-\mu X_1 - X_2)dt +\sigma dW_1$ and
$dX_2=(-\mu X_2 + X_1)dt +\sigma dW_2$

I then have to show that $E(X_1^2 + X_2^2) = \frac{\sigma^2}{\mu}$.

I know I have to use the multidimensional Ito formula, however I am not too sure how to set everything up.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: The initial conditions are $X_1 = 1$ and $X_2=0$

Comment: Somehow there is an exponential term missing in the claimed solution. Or do you mean to express the asymptotic limit?

Comment: Yeah, as a limit. (should've put that.

Answer (score 1):

The one dimensional SDE
$$
dX_t=AX_t\,dt+\sigma W_t
$$
has the solution
$$\tag{1}
X_t=e^{At}\textstyle(X_0+\sigma\int_0^te^{-As}\,dW_s)\,.
$$
When you replace the constant $A$ by the matrix
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}-\mu&-1\\1&-\mu\end{matrix}\right)
$$
and $X$ resp. $W$ by their two dimensional sisters then you will see that (1) is the solution to your system.

Comment: Your matrix is wrong, the entries of the last row need to be switched.

Comment: Thanks. Hope it is right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply Ito to $Y=X_1^2+X_2^2$, then
$$\begin{align}
dY &= 2(X_1dX_1+X_2dX_2)+(dX_1)^2+(dX_2)^2
\\
&= -2\mu(X_1^2+X_2^2)\,dt+2\sigma(X_1dW_1+X_2dW_2)+2\sigma^2\,dt,
\end{align}$$
using the informal notation for the increment of the quadratic variation.

Going over to the expectation removes the terms with Brownian increments, resulting in
$$
dE(Y)=-2\mu\,E(Y)\,dt+2\sigma^2\,dt.
$$
This now is a standard first-order linear ODE, converging to an equilibrium that is indeed located at $\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu}$